# Why is Sefer Tehillim called Tehillim and not Tehillos?

Tags: names, grammar-dikduk, tehilim-psalms

Tehillim is plural of Tehilla (תהלה). Tehilla looks like a feminine noun, which is why there's a word called תהלות.

So why is the sefer called Sefer Tehillim?

Comment: Hebrew not Judaism?

Comment: @andrewmh20, I think we can call this on-topic, as it deals with a sefer in Tanach. Grammar in Tanach IS on-topic, AFAIK.

Comment: FWIW, the Arabic title is a translation of "Mizmorim"

Comment: Note that it *is* sometimes called "_T'hilos_".

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt it's not a word in Tanach, it's just about grammar relating to our name for a book of Tanach.

Comment: Also, it was commonly called Tillim, see Avoda Zara 19a for example.

Comment: @andrewmh20, yes, it's "about grammar relating to our name for a book of Tanach", which makes it about ["language used in Judaism"](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1474) and puts it squarely within our scope.

Comment: Interesting point! Just before Shacahrit Shemoneh Esreh, we DO say "TEHILLOT L'El Elyon"!

Comment: Ibn Ezra and Malbim, both grammarians, called it ספר תהילות

Comment: Source for Yosef Weiner about Ibn Ezra [over here](https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms.150.6.1?vhe=Ibn_Ezra_on_Psalms_--_Daat&lang=he)

Comment: Source for Yosef Weiner about Malbim [over here](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_I_Chronicles.16.23.1?vhe=Malbim_on_I_Chronicles_--_Wikisource&lang=he) and also [over here](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Genesis.19.18.1?vhe=Malbim_on_Genesis_--_Wikisource&lang=he). Interestingly, he calls it תהלים [over here](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Deuteronomy.7.9.1?vhe=Mikraei_Kodesh,_Vilna,_1891&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) Apparantly the Malbim was almost put in cherem for calling it תהלות and not תהילים.

Answer (score 4):

It’s basically chazal’s version of The Praises. It is a way to distinguish it from random praises. It is a formal noun. Another example is that Teffilin is called teffilin to make it a formal noun, and to distinguish it from tefillot.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, where we value sourced answers. (After all, nobody knows who I am, so nobody has any reason to trust what I say unless I support it.) Specifically, this claim is interesting and seems somewhat plausible, but do you have any source or argument in its support? In any event, I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including its 222 other [tag:grammar-dikduk] questions. Please consider [registering](/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) more site features.