# Why is the name "Tre Asar" in Aramaic?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, names, tanach, aramaic

All the books of Tanach are either named after a person, or are given a Hebrew name, except for Tre Asar, which is Aramaic. One would have expected the Hebrew title Shinem Asar, and indeed it is called that in the Gemara (eg. Bava Batra 15a).

Any sources on what historical phenomena caused this?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17023/759